# Match literal equal sign

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

What is the syntax to match exactly a literal equal sign (=) in some column with awk?

I tried (matching at column 2):

```
cat $file | awk '$2 == ='
cat $file | awk '$2 == \='
cat $file | awk '$2 =~ /=/'
cat $file | awk '$2 =~ /\=/'
cat $file | awk '$2 =~ /"="/'
```

but am always getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need :

```
awk  ' $2 == "=" ' yourfile
```

OR

```
awk  ' $2 ~ /^=$/ ' yourfile
```

There is no need of `cat file | awk ...`

and there is no operators like `=~` in `awk`